# Ruby search for comma separated string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am kind of new to Ruby on Rails and can't figure out how to store a string of numbers with commas in it into the database. Ever attempted I make at doing this it turns the the list into an array and takes the first item.

for example: "12,34,56,78,90" it would save this as 12

The same thing goes for when I am trying to search for that string. This doesn't make any sense to me why Rails wants to convert a string into an array and take the first element. I haven't been able to find away around this. Any help would be appreciated!

Below is the sample of my code that I want to get working.

```
if DeviceApprovalQueue.find_by_address(params[:address]).nil?
  daq = DeviceApprovalQueue.new(device_id: params[:gateway_id], address: params[:address])
  if daq.save
    #Device is queued
  end
else
  #Already queued
end
```

Comment: Please show the schema for the table you are trying to write to and the exact error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This doesn't make any sense to me why Rails wants to convert a string into an array and take the first element.

Because this is not what happens here. You have an integer column. So `12` is the result of casting your string to integer.

```
'12,34,56,78,90'.to_i # => 12
```

Now you could store it in a string column, but then it's just a string. You lose all its properties as a "list of integers".

You could store it in array column. But this a) requires you to parse it beforehand and b) is not a widely supported column type.

Perhaps, you need to do something else. Hard to say.

Comment: Thank you, You are completely right my column was the wrong type.